# C++: Difference between std::list<type*> and std::list<*type>

Tags: c++

Im currently learning C++ and I have seen an iterator doing the following:

```
for(std::list<Type*>::iterator iter = list.begin();
 iter != list.end(); ++iter) {

 if (!isInRange(**iter)) {
 iter = list.erase(**iter);
 }
}
```

Now, my question is: How do I know whether a double pointer is used or not? To get the object of iter, the solution uses two `**`, but the declaration of the iterator defines the type as a single pointer, not double pointer: `<Type*>`. Is there a difference between `std::list<Type*>` and `std::list<*Type>`? If a `*` on the right side of the type means, that it is a double pointer, then I would understand why I would need to use two `**` in order to get the object.

Thank you very much in advance!
Qioda

Comment: Your question title is inconsistent with your example code, where are you actually using `std::list<*Type>`?

Comment: I have seen the usage of *Type is other scenarios, thats where my question came from. I was wondering, if it makes a difference on which side the * is.

Comment: `std::list<type*>` is a list of `type` pointers, `std::list<*type>` is a syntax error and invalid C++

Comment: `std::list<*T>` doesn't work: https://godbolt.org/z/obfvThvsf Can you show an example of where you see this being used?

Comment: _"I have seen the usage of *Type ..."_ give us a [mcve] of such scenario please. As mentioned it's not valid c++ in the context of a template parameter.

Comment: you cannot know if there are pointers to pointers unless you know what `Type` is. Imho there are definitely too many `*`s in the code

Comment: iterator defines an `operator *()` that returns the value at the iterator's position. You have a vector of pointers. This code retrieves the pointer from the iterator and then dereferences the pointer to get an actual value of `type`

Comment: `*` has indeed several meaning, [pointers explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/book/pointers) might help.

Comment: I have seen the usage of *Type outside of templates. That's what I meant. I just wanna know why they used the double ** in this scenario.

Comment: Thank you @vpa1977 :) Thats what I wanted to know!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on your main question:

> How do I know whether a double pointer is used or not

You are creating a list storing pointers of type Type (`Type*`), and you are using a [`std:list<T>:iterator`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/) in order to iterate over this list.

An iterator basically references to a node of the list. It is, "by definition", a pointer.

The values you are storing in your list are pointers of type Type (Type*). And you are referencing a value (Type*) using an iterator.

- The variable iter is your iterator. It references a value on your list (Type*).
- The instruction `*iter` will return a `Type*` (pointer of type `Type`).
- The instruction `**iter` will return a `Type` (value of type `Type`).

Summing up, you always need to use `*iter` to obtain the value referenced by the iterator. You need `**iter` if you created a list storing pointers and you want to obtain the value referenced by the pointer stored in your list.

About the last line of the code you provided `iter = list.erase(**iter)` you have to use `iter` instead of `**iter`, because the `erase` method requires an iterator as a parameter, not a `Type`.

Finally, if you create a list of `Type` instead of a list of `Type*`, `*iter` would return a value of type `Type`.

Please, try to formulate your questions in a clearer way.